# TypeScript: File 'XXX' is not a module

Tags: json, angular, typescript, module, visual-studio-code

I want to import a module declared in an external file into an other TS file. But VSCode says that the **file 'XXX' is not a module**:

[The illustrated error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5q1R3.jpg)

I tried [this possible fix](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/10391) but it doesn't work. Any idea?

Comment: are both files in the same folder?

Comment: Yes, they are in the same folder.

Comment: then you shouldnt need the `./` at the start of the file include

Comment: Nope, it's not working: https://i.stack.imgur.com/VB5DQ.png

Comment: Im curious why you are using Ambient Modules here? do you just want to export the interface do you have a use-case for declaring an ambient module? anyway, read on ambient modules here: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/modules.html#ambient-modules

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In **ectm-apidatafmsproperties.ts**, I changed **declare module IApiDataFMsProperties** by **export module IApiDataFMsProperties** and now it's working.

But I'm not sure if it's the right solution... Can someone tell me something about this possible fix?